# Where to store my custom scripts with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, path, conventions

I'd like to know where to store scripts that my jenkins build process use.
For now I've stored them under the workspace directory, but I'm afraid that it should end up with those scripts beeing lost.

What is the recommandation/convention?
Should I put them under my `$JENKINS_HOME/vendor`, under `/var/usr/jenkins-vendor` or elsewhere?

Should I use a plugin to manage this for me so I do not have to manually create this directory by hand?

Comment: Well, our build scripts are usually checked into the git repositiory we're building. This approach has advantages as well as caveats, but you might want to consider it.

Comment: if you are talking about jenkins dsl and/or pipeline groovy script, I would suggest to have separate repository for them and store there